# Rendering view outside of controllerContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razorengine

I have a project written in .net Core mvc6. I have an "HideExeptionsMiddleware", which goal is to catch the thrown exceptions which are not handled in the controllers, as a last resort, and redirect the user to the error page. The middleware also logs the exeptions, and generates a unique ID for the error.
My goal is to pass that ID, along with other "ViewBag" variables to the Error.chtml file, without redirecting the response!

The solution I tought of is to render the .chtml file to a string, and use
Response.WriteAsync from the middleware.

I know its a question that been asked before, but the common solution found is
using RazorEngine (https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/), but it seams in-active and the examples online/documentation is of a much older versions and I could not make it work.

Its hard to believe there isn't a simple solution like passing a path to the chtml file, along with model+viewbag and getting a string back.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly the official error handler middleware does, but it offers the ability to *rewrite* the request, which means it doesn't redirect. Instead it just executes the middleware stack again with another URL. I think this is something you could do as well. It would make it easier since you could pass the params in query parameters and have MVC figure them out.

Comment: Changing the path and invoking the context again its impossible. I get the exception "headers already sent". But even so, I don't want to pass the error ID to the action.

Comment: Rendering view requires controller context which is not available in your middle-ware. I think `RazorEngine` is a way to go. Otherwise make a simple html without `Razor`.

Answer (score 3):

There already exists a middleware provided by ASP.NET Core that handle this case. It is accessible throw the `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` extension on your `IApplicationBuilder` instance.
The idea is to configure this middleware with a route dedicated to error handling which will return the configured error view with technical information.

In your Startup's Configure method:

```
...
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
...
```

Then define a ErrorController:

```
[Route("error")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet("{status?}")]
   public IActionResult Index(int? status = null)
   {
        ViewBag.RequestId = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        return this.View();
   }
}
```